# What's AfD's vision for the Ukrainian refugees in Germany?

Tags: ukraine, parties, germany, refugees

[Reportedly](https://time.com/6240005/germany-far-right-ukraine-war/)

> While protesting in Leipzig in October against Russia’s war in Ukraine, Anastasia, 21, was confronted by AfD counter-protesters screaming “Nazis out” at her and fellow Ukrainians.

The AfD also opposes weapon deliveries to Ukraine and wants to reestablish energy imports from Russia (same source, but TASS is [also](https://tass.com/world/1559909) quite happy to quote AfD leaders on these two issues. Somewhat tongue-in-cheek, AfD's stance on these two issues [weapons and energy] has been called the "conversion to Merkelism" of the AfD--not by TASS, of course, but [by](https://www.spectator.co.uk/article/the-afd-s-unlikely-conversion-to-merkelism/) *The Spectator*.)

So, what's AfD's [official] vision for the Ukrainian refugees?

Answer (score 4):

Acording to [this article](https://www.bundestag.de/dokumente/textarchiv/2022/kw14-de-masterplan-hilfe-889116):

> **AfD calls for prevention of free riders**
>
> Gottfried Curio (AfD) emphasized that the all-round support for the
> Ukrainian refugees was "unquestionable", but effective help could only
> work "if the helpers have control over what they are doing". Security
> authorities warned that smugglers are actively promoting easier entry
> conditions and circulating fake Ukrainian passports. Germany is
> therefore also open to terrorist groups.

And an [other article](https://www.rnd.de/politik/krieg-in-der-ukraine-afd-fuer-aufnahme-von-fluechtlingen-2E656TZUND652TWFK7M2HAV5QM.html):

> **AfD for taking in war refugees from Ukraine**
>
> In recent years, the AfD has made a name for itself as an anti-asylum
> party. Their actual view: Refugees should seek refuge in the nearest
> safe country. After the Russian invasion of Ukraine, she rethinks, at
> least temporarily.
>
> Berlin. AfD chairman Tino Chrupalla has spoken out in favor of taking
> in war refugees from Ukraine in Germany.
>
> “The Ukrainians are not responsible for the acts of war. They
> experience suffering and pain through the death of relatives and
> friends and the destruction of their homeland," said the party and
> parliamentary group leader on Monday when asked. "Therefore, Ukrainian
> war refugees should find support in Germany and throughout Europe so
> that they can return home strengthened once the conflict situation has
> eased."
>
> In recent years, the AfD has made a name for itself as an anti-asylum
> party and believes that refugees should seek refuge in the nearest
> safe country.
>
> Their parliamentarians had clearly condemned Russia's war of aggression in
> Ukraine on Sunday in the Bundestag. However, they blamed the West and
> the federal government, and thus caused great irritation among MPs
> from other parliamentary groups. The CDU politician Sepp Müller from
> Saxony-Anhalt acknowledged the speech of the AfD MP Petr Bystron
> according to the record with the heckling "Putin propaganda".

So in this situation they are not as anti refugy, as they normaly are.

Comment: note "Their actual view: Refugees should seek refuge in the nearest safe country" is only because the nearest safe country is never Germany. If the nearest safe country was Germany, they would come up with a different view, like "refugees should seek refuge in a country with close ties to their homeland" or something like that. Right-wingers do this thing a lot.

Comment: I believe that AfD would be more than happy to accept refugees from e.g. German-speaking parts of Switzerland in the extremely unlikely event of a civil war in it.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that AfD will be sympathetic towards Ukrainian refugees staying in Germany and acquiring citizenship, for the simple reason that they're potential voters.

It looks like significant demographic segment voting for AfD is "Soviet Germans", i.e., German, Jewish and Russian repatriants coming from Russia, Kazakhstan and Ukraine after the collapse of USSR.

The Ukrainian refugees represent the same demographics and would likely blend in the same communities and will often vote for AfD in years to come (provided that it still caters to this audience). So it is in their best interests to keep Ukrainian refugees in Germany and also integrate them into existing ex-Soviet citizens' communities.

Comment: -1 the idea that Jewish people would vote in significant numbers for a german right-wing extremist party with ties to Nazism really requires some sources. As does the idea that the afd would be sympathetic towards any refugees. And Refugees can of course not vote, but the idea that ukrainian refugees would vote for a party with [ties to Russia](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/innenpolitik/afd-russland-115.html) is also questionable.

Comment: You seem to greatly downplay culture while overvaluing short term politics. Ukrainian refugees are still overwhelmingly Russian-speaking Eastern Europeans with post-Soviet culture. Do you expect them to hang out with Syrians and vote Social Democrat?

Comment: @tim Disagree about calling AfD a nazi party, sure there are some antisemits there but other german parties also have antisemits as members. However since AfD is relative Russia friendly and anti EU, makes it not really atractive for Ukrainians.

Comment: @convert It's a right-wing extremist party that's observed as such by the state. And it has ties to Nazism (eg employing Nazis in the bavarian parliament, ideological ties with Höcke and his followers, etc). I didn't call them a Nazi party, but they are at least in part one; in other parts it's different variants of far-right extremism.

Comment: @convert And what grounds do you disagree with that? And we're not talking about backseat noname politicians but their top politicians and party leadership.

Comment: @convert "Ausland aus!" ring any bells?

Comment: @convert I'm not sure why you assume Ukrainian refugees to be big fans of Zelensky and continue being loyal to his line of action for years to come. After all, becoming a refugee is an implicit disagreement to participate in what happens under his rule.

Comment: @alamar please do not speak about the issues you have no idea. Reasonable amount of refugees are wife and children of military personal. They left not because they disagree, but because this creates less stress for a guy who sits in the trenches. Another group are people whose houses were destroyed. Of course, in your view, those are the types of people who are big fans of Putin.

Comment: Are these the only two options available? Do you have to be a fan of either one eastern european presidents?

Comment: There are other options available. But you are the guy who started with 'they left Ukraine, so they are against what Zelensky is doing'. Or was it someone else who wrote stupidity about 'implicit disagreement'?

Comment: I wonder if you have any data on the amount of people leaving because of their implicit disagreement vs. amount of those who are all for the fighting till the very end while they are spending time in another country?